# Adding words to a list which contains certain letters within a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string and I want to find the words containing 'th' in it and add them to a list. But I do not want a words which contains 'T'.

The final list cannot have any repeated word in it.

```
thestring = "The character that can fire the. bullet that sheriff dodged"
a = "th"
b = "T"

def makelists(thestring, a, b)
    """
    >>> makelists(thestring, 'th', 'T')
    ['that', 'the.']
    """
```

So far I have only got this, and it is printing out repeated words.

```
def makelists(thestring, a, b)
    words = thestring.split()
    thelist = [] 
    for word in words:
        if a in word:
            thelist.append(word)           
    for char in thelist:
        if b in char:
            thelist.remove(char)
    print thelist
```

The output I get is ['that', 'the.', 'that'].

What edit can be done to my code for which a output will be ['that', 'the.']

Comment: You could simply make `thelist` a [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/set.html), then duplicates are handled for you.

Comment: `set(i for i in thestring.split() if a in i)`

Comment: words = set(thestring.split()). Just change line 2.

Answer (score 2):

Though your code is very long and you must optimise it, You could check before adding in the list:-

```
def makelists(thestring, a, b)
    words = thestring.split()
    thelist = [] 
    for word in words:
        if a in word and word not in thelist:
            thelist.append(word)           
    for char in thelist:
        if b in char:
            thelist.remove(char)
    print thelist
```

Or, the other solution is to do:-

```
thelist = list(set(thelist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set and you can even shorten the code with a nicer if statement:

```
def makelists(thestring, a, b):
    words = thestring.split()
    thelist = set([]) 
    for word in words:
        if a in word and b not in word:
            thelist.add(word)          
    print thelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using re module and list comprehensions like this:

```
import re
thestring = "The character that can fire the. bullet that sheriff dodged"    
a = "th"
b = "T"

print list(set([word  for word in re.split(" +", thestring) if a in word and b not in word ]))
```